# PHP Bidimensional array and foreach loops

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, nested

I follow struggling with bidimensional arrays and foreach loops. The following code shows a magazines array, each of them points to an unidimensional Articles array. Right now is storing three Articles for each magazine (just the Article's Title). I would like to know how to associate a Bidimensional array so that can I store the Author and PagesNumber besides the Title, for each article belonging a magazine. Could you point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

// Create a magazines array
$magazines = array();

// Put 5 magazines on it
for($x=0;$x<5;$x++)
    $magazines[] = "Magazine " . $x ;

// Associate articles array to each magazine
foreach($magazines as $magazine){
    $articles[$magazine] = array();
    for($x=0;$x<3;$x++)
        $articles[$magazine][] = $magazine . " - Article Title " . $x ;
}

// List them all
foreach($magazines as $magazine){
    echo $magazine . " has these articles: <br>";
    foreach($articles[$magazine] as $article)
        echo $article . "</br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should structure it a little different:

```
$magazines = array();

//create magazines
for($x=0;$x<5;$x++) {
  $magazines[] = array('name' => 'Magazine ' . $x, 
                       'year' => '2011', 
                       'articles' => array());
}

//fill in some articles
foreach ($magazines as &$magazine) {
  for($x=0;$x<3;$x++) {
    $magazine['articles'][] = array('article_titel' => $magazine['name'] . " - Article Title " . $x, 
                                    'article_author' => 'author ' . $x,
                                    'article_page' => $x);
  }
}

//output
foreach($magazines as $magazine) {
  echo 'The Magazine ' . $magazine['name'] . ' from ' . $magazine['year'] . ' contains the articles : ';
  foreach($magazine['articles'] as $article) {
    echo $article['article_titel'] . ' by ' . $article['article_author'] . ' on page ' . $article['article_page'];
  }
}
```

A little explaination:
Magazines is a normal array.
Then you add associative arrays to it (magazines).
Each magzines-array has an articles-field, which is a normal array, which you add associative arrays to again (articles).

So now, you iterate throug magazines, and each magazine has an array of articles which you can iterate.

That means: Magazines is an array of single magazines, one magazine is an associative array, which also contains an array of articles. An article is an associative array again.

I hope that sounds not too confusing... ;)

Comment: Sounds good. However, is not listing any articles. Also, you forgot the period at echo 'The Magazine ' $magazine['name']

Comment: @Jorge thanks for the hint. Although I can't explain, why the articles-array is empty... I guess there's a typo somewhere, because it's not wrong - that's how I always do it :) I'll try to fix that!

Comment: Me neither, but your code is what I'm looking for (of course working ;) lol . Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: @Jorge alright, I've fixed the code - while filling in articles (or generally, while writing to sub-arrays in loops), you have to reference the $magazine directly with & - stupid mistake :-P

Comment: Wow... that's really cool. Thank you so much, I really appreciate your code and your time.

Comment: @christian-sciberras Excuse me? What do you mean? Are you saying, that I've copied it off somewhere? This is just a slightly modified version of Jorge's code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the extra information in an associative array within the magazine entry:

```
for ( $m = 0; $m < 5; $m++ ) {
    for ( $a = 0; $a < 3; $a++ ) {
        $magazines["Magazine $m"]["Article $a"] = array(
            'title'  => "Title $a",
            'author' => "Author $a"
        );
    }
}
```

You can then access each element in the array in a variety of ways:

```
// foreach loops through each element of the array,
// returning the key and value:
foreach ( $magazines as $magazine => $articles ) {
    print "$magazine\n";
    foreach ( $articles as $article => $info ) {
        print "  $article\n";
        // You can also access elements directly by their key:
        print "    Title: {$info['title']}\n";
        print "    Author: {$info['author']}\n";
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Magazine 0
  Article 0
    Title: Title 0
    Author: Author 0
  Article 1
    Title: Title 1
    Author: Author 1
  Article 2
    Title: Title 2
    Author: Author 2
Magazine 1
  Article 0
    Title: Title 0
    Author: Author 0
  ...
```

There are many ways of creating a nested array, and the choice depends on your requirements.  The above method used only associative arrays, whereas the following used both associative arrays and numeric arrays:

```
$magazines = array();

for ( $m = 0; $m < 5; $m++ ) {
    $magazines[$m] = array( 'title' => "Magazine $m" );
    for ( $a = 0; $a < 3; $a++ ) {
        $magazines[$m]['articles'][] = array(
            'title'  => "Article $a",
            'author' => "Author $a"
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Just three things, if you are getting that output, I suppose you have another line above to set plain text headers. Maybe something like header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
Second, in my real example I don't know how many magazines and articles I'm going to have, that's the reason I used $magazines[] = in my code. Third, what I want to understand is how to use nested foreach, print_r is great for debugging but not any help here for output purposes. Thanks.

Comment: @Jorge: I run the sample in the CLI shell, so they are output directly to the console, not to a browser.  If you are looping through an unknown number of arrays, you can create your own counter in a `while` loop, or just tag elements onto the end of a numeric array with `[]`.  Associative arrays need a unique key name, hence building the name as part of the loop.  I've updated my answer with an alternative output, to show accessing the array.  I've also added another example of creating the array.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I mixing your last code for creating the arrays with your nested foreach. I don't know if that is what I'm suppose to do. Anyway, if you do that, the output is pretty weird! ;)

Comment: @Jorge: I think you may need to learn more about arrays and how they work. The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) is a good place to start, but you could also search for tutorials on the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

```
// 5 articles per magazine:
$articles = array_combine($magazines, array_fill(0, 5, array(1,2,3,4,5));
```

You now have 5 articles per magazine all with a number as their title. Just for the demo. Hope it helps. You can access all articles via the `$articles` array then by providing the magazine title as key.

Naturally you can set the articles for each magazine manually as well:

```
$articles[$magazine] = array('My first article', 'Editorial', 'Cooking with wood fire');
```

Or even individually:

```
$articles[$magazine][] = 'Learning by doing.';
```

**Edit:** If an article has more to offer then a title:

```
$articles[$magazine][] = array
(
  'title' => 'Learning by doing.',
  'author' => 'Frank Stein',
  'pages' => 2,
);
```

Comment: Two questions. In my real code, I don't know how many magazines and how many articles I'm going to have. That's the reason I'm using $magazines[] = and $articles[$magazine][] = . Second, I would like to understand how to operate with nested foreach. Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do with nested (also called multi-dimensional) arrays? In your question you also operate the output on them which looks good.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't know how to operate with more than one column in php. Right now is working with the Title, but I also need to add Author and Pages. It's a simple example for something more complex I'm doing by iterating objects at Amazon S3. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Jorge, if you need more values inside each article and you want to use `array` for that, you need to additionally add them. I'll extend the answer.

Comment: Cool, I got it. How can I output the whole thing using nested foreach? Regards.

Comment: I finally got it by reading the Quasdunk example. Thanks anyway for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I follow the issue here. Why not use the following?

```
$magazines = array(

    array( // a single magazine
        'title' => 'Issue 1',
        'articles' => array( // a list of articles
            array( // a single article
                title => 'Article 1',
                content => 'xyz'
            )
        )
    ),

);
```

Edit: Fixed small mistake :)

If you want to make it in a more readable manner, you can do:

```
function Magazines(){
    return func_get_args();
}

function Magazine($title,$articles){
    return array(
        'title' => $title,
        'articles' => $articles
    );
}

function Articles(){
    return func_get_args();
}

function Article($title,$content){
    return array(
        'title' => $title,
        'content' => $content
    );
}

// and using it...
$magazines = Magazines(Magazine('Issue 1',Articles(Article('Article 1','xyz'))));
```

It just replaces `array()` with some good naming. You can easily convert this (or something similar) to OOP. At the end, OOP is just for managing the items. The actual storage is always an array.

---

**Traversal**

Reading through the array is actually quite simple once you have the right structure:

```
foreach($magazines as $magazine){
    // user things like $magazine['title'] in here...
    foreach($magazine['articles'] as $article){
        // user $article['title'] here
    }
}
```

That's **6** lines of clean code.

Comment: I appreciate it. However, my point is to understand how to operate with arrays properly and specially how to operate with nested foreach.

Comment: I've waited over 10 minutes for a reply/clarification. I think you do owe me a second chance. Anyway, edited answer...

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
$magazines[$magazine] = array();
$magazines[$magazine]['article']['title'] = 'title';
$magazines[$magazine]['article']['other'] = 'other';

foreach ($magazines as $name => $magazine) {
    echo "name: " . $name;
    foreach ($magazine as $articleName => $article) {
        echo "title: " . $article['title'] . "\n";
        echo "other: " . $article['other'] . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, thank you, but I don't know how your array $magazines[$magazine] is related to my example.